# Flex SharedObject Crash

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I am working on a flex project using sharedobjects to store information on my server. I am not 100% sure how to do this, so I was looking up tutorials and came across this bit of code:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("rtmp://[website here]");
so = SharedObject.getRemote("ballPosition", nc.uri, false);
so.connect(nc);
```

But when it gets to the 3rd line, it crashes. I don't know how to use the debugger for flex sadly enough, which I am looking into now, but I figured that I would post this here and hope for the best. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started posting this as a comment, but it quickly got too long..

You may be getting the error because you're not connected to the server. If you're connected then you'll get a `true` returned from your second line. I'd start there. eg:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
var c = nc.connect("rtmp://[website here]");
trace(c);
so = SharedObject.getRemote("ballPosition", nc.uri, false);
so.connect(nc);
```

Also, you might try wrapping this in a try/catch block as that will give you the error, but won't kill your app (since you're new to debugging).

```
try {
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect("rtmp://[website here]");
    so = SharedObject.getRemote("ballPosition", nc.uri, false);
    so.connect(nc);
} catch(e:Error) {
    trace("my sweet error is:", e);
}
```

In all, debugging is simply awesome and can save you a lot of time in certain situations. good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that is where it came from, I didn't realize that was a boolean, I need to learn a bit more about flex. If I am on the server, as in, I have my flex package uploaded to the server, shouldn't it be able to connect to it? I am guessing that I may not have enough permission on the server, my boss didn't really give me a lot to work with :p

Comment: if they are on the same server, you might try connecting to `localhost` instead of an *IP* or *domain name* to see if that does the trick.